# Training NER model to parse temporal and location expressionsions

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

Folks, does anybody has thoughts on building NER models for labeling text sequences like addresses or temporal expressions?

There is a parser for temporal expressions like "last five days" called SUTime: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml. Unfortunately, it's buggy and built as massive mash of rules.

Parsing addresses is even more difficult and error prone. CoreNLP parser fails to parse even simple things like Mountain View, CA.

I feel that there should be a way to train RNN to recognize these patterns without maintaining a giant list of rules or a giant lookup table.

Comment: there are a lot of deeplearning libraries available in different languages. did you check those?

Answer (score 1):

> does anybody has thoughts on building NER models for labeling text sequences like addresses or temporal expressions?

Yes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475 use RNN for NER.

Figure 1 gives an overview of the ANN architecture:

[image]